# Put Flutter-Quill toolbar at the top of page or container

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to put the `flutter-quill` toolbar at the top of the page, above the editor but below the `title` of the `AppBar` but whatever I try won't work.

I tried to create a `Container(child: toolbar)` but because `var toolbar` is at the bottom of the code, `toolbar` is not declared at the `AppBar` stage.

So I tried to move the `var toolbar` code to the top of `main.dart` and that produced a bunch of errors.

Below `toolbar` code is straight from `flutter-quill` Github:

```
var toolbar = QuillToolbar.basic(
      controller: _controller!,
      embedButtons: FlutterQuillEmbeds.buttons(
        // provide a callback to enable picking images from device.
        // if omit, "image" button only allows adding images from url.
        // same goes for videos.
        onImagePickCallback: _onImagePickCallback,
        onVideoPickCallback: _onVideoPickCallback,
        // uncomment to provide a custom "pick from" dialog.
        // mediaPickSettingSelector: _selectMediaPickSetting,
        // uncomment to provide a custom "pick from" dialog.
        // cameraPickSettingSelector: _selectCameraPickSetting,
      ),
      showAlignmentButtons: true,
      afterButtonPressed: _focusNode.requestFocus,
    );
    if (kIsWeb) {
      toolbar = QuillToolbar.basic(
        controller: _controller!,
        embedButtons: FlutterQuillEmbeds.buttons(
          onImagePickCallback: _onImagePickCallback,
          webImagePickImpl: _webImagePickImpl,
        ),
        showAlignmentButtons: true,
        afterButtonPressed: _focusNode.requestFocus,
      );
    }
    if (_isDesktop()) {
      toolbar = QuillToolbar.basic(
        controller: _controller!,
        embedButtons: FlutterQuillEmbeds.buttons(
          onImagePickCallback: _onImagePickCallback,
          filePickImpl: openFileSystemPickerForDesktop,
        ),
        showAlignmentButtons: true,
        afterButtonPressed: _focusNode.requestFocus,
      );
    }

    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 15,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
              child: quillEditor,
            ),
          ),
          kIsWeb
              ? Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 8),
                  child: toolbar,
                ))
              : Container(child: toolbar)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The `AppBar` is from `flutter-quill`:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'Flutter Quill',
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => _addEditNote(context),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.note_add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: _buildMenuBar(context),
      ),
      body: toolbar // I removed this "_buildWelcomeEditor(context)," but failed
    );
  }
```

I tried below and failed:

```
body: Column(
children [
toolbar,
_buildWelcomeEditor(context)
],),
```

Two questions:

1. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?
2. I thought Dart was Ahead-of-time Compiled so it would read the whole file before compiling and `var toolbar` declared at the end could still be used at the beginning of the program. Why didn't it work?